# Update Vora Cluster : processing failed

Tags: vora

Am setting up Vora 2.1 on an AWS KOPS setup.

```
    ./install.sh --accept-license --deployment-type=cloud --enable-rbac=no  --namespace=vora --docker-registry=<localrepository>:5000 --vora-admin-username=voraadmin --vora-admin-password=<secret> --cert-domain=<custeromerdomain> --interactive-security-configuration=no --vsystem-storage-class=aws-efs --vsystem-load-nfs-modules
```

Below is my error:

```
Wait until pod vora-deployment-operator-cc84bff65-hgtt4 is running...
Wait until containers in the pod vora-deployment-operator-cc84bff65-hgtt4 are ready...
Wait until voracluster CRD is created...
No resources found.
Deploying vora-cluster with: helm install --namespace vora -f values.yaml -f /install/SAPVora-2.1.60-DistributedRuntime/stateful-replica-conf.yaml   --set docker.registry=172.20.41.35:5000   --set rbac.enabled=false   --set imagePullSecret=   --set docker.imagePullSecret=   --set version.package=2.1.60 --set docker.image=vora/dqp --set docker.imageTag=2.1.32.25-vora-2.1 --set components.globalParameters.security.docker.image=vora/init-security --set components.globalParameters.security.docker.imageTag=0.0.9 --set components.globalParameters.security.enable=true --set components.globalParameters.security.context=consumer --set components.globalParameters.security.contextRoot=/etc/vora-security --set version.component=2.1.32.25-vora-2.1 --set name=vora --set dontUseExternalStorage=false --set useHostPath=false --set components.disk.useHostPath=false --set components.dlog.useHostPath=false  .
NAME:   quaffing-cow
LAST DEPLOYED: Thu Mar 29 09:53:24 2018
NAMESPACE: vora
STATUS: DEPLOYED

RESOURCES:
==> v1/VoraCluster
NAME  KIND
vora  VoraCluster.v1.sap.com


Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Unable to get an update from the "local" chart repository (http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts):
        Get http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts/index.yaml: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8879: getsockopt: connection refused
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈
Saving 1 charts
Downloading consul from repo https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
Deleting outdated charts
vora-vsystem is already installed, skipping...
Deploying vora-thriftserver with: helm install --namespace vora -f values.yaml -f /install/SAPVora-2.1.60-DistributedRuntime/stateful-replica-conf.yaml   --set docker.registry=172.20.41.35:5000   --set rbac.enabled=false   --set imagePullSecret=   --set docker.imagePullSecret=   --set version.package=2.1.60 --set thriftserver.docker.image=vora/thriftserver --set thriftserver.docker.imageTag=2.1.14.25-vora-2.1 --set auth.enable=true --set secop.ctxRoot=/etc/vora-security --set secop.ctxName=consumer --set secop.docker.image=vora/init-security --set secop.docker.imageTag=0.0.9 --set version.component=2.1.14.25-vora-2.1 .
NAME:   knotted-macaw
LAST DEPLOYED: Thu Mar 29 09:53:29 2018
NAMESPACE: vora
STATUS: DEPLOYED

RESOURCES:
==> v1/Service
NAME               CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)    AGE
vora-thriftserver  100.69.133.27  <none>       10001/TCP  1s

==> v1beta1/Deployment
NAME               DESIRED  CURRENT  UP-TO-DATE  AVAILABLE  AGE
vora-thriftserver  1        1        1           0          1s


Authentication is enabled!
Running validation...
Wait until vora cluster is ready...
Wait until vora cluster is ready...
...........
Wait until vora cluster is ready...
Wait until vora cluster is ready...
Timeout while waiting for vora cluster! See below for more details:
Name:         vora
Namespace:    vora
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  sap.com/v1
Kind:         VoraCluster
Metadata:
  Cluster Name:
  Creation Timestamp:  2018-03-29T09:53:24Z
  Generation:          0
  Resource Version:    497995
  Self Link:           /apis/sap.com/v1/namespaces/vora/voraclusters/vora
  UID:                 055fc3ab-3337-11e8-8c30-0aa4c3a975fc
Spec:
  Components:
    Catalog:
      Replicas:     1
      Trace Level:  info
    Disk:
      Db Space Size:            10000
      Initial Delay Seconds:    180
      Large Memory Limit:       3000
      Main Cache Memory Limit:  3000
      Network Drivers List:     none
      Pv:
        Volume Claim Annotations:        <nil>
      Replicas:                          1
      Storage Size:                      50Gi
      Temporary Cache Memory Limit:      3000
      Termination Grace Period Seconds:  300
      Trace Level:                       info
    Dlog:
      Buffer Size:            4g
      Initial Delay Seconds:  15
      Pv:
        Volume Claim Annotations:        <nil>
      Replication Factor:                2
      Standby Factor:                    1
      Storage Size:                      50Gi
      Termination Grace Period Seconds:  60
      Trace Level:                       info
    Doc Store:
      Replicas:     1
      Trace Level:  info
    Global Parameters:
      Health Check:
        Deregister Timeout:                2m
        Initial Delay Seconds:             15
        Period Seconds:                    5
        Termination Grace Period Seconds:  60
      Security:
        Context:       consumer
        Context Root:  /etc/vora-security
        Image:         172.20.41.35:5000/vora/init-security:0.0.9
      Trace Level:     info
    Graph:
      Replicas:     1
      Trace Level:  info
    Landscape:
      Bootstrapping:       True
      Replicas:            1
      Replication Factor:  1
      Trace Level:         info
    Relational:
      Replicas:     1
      Trace Level:  info
    Time Series:
      Replicas:     1
      Trace Level:  info
    Tx Broker:
      Replicas:     1
      Trace Level:  info
    Tx Coordinator:
      Node Port:     0
      Replicas:      1
      Service Type:  NodePort
      Trace Level:   info
    Tx Lock Manager:
      Replicas:     1
      Trace Level:  info
  Docker:
    Image:              172.20.41.35:5000/vora/dqp:2.1.32.25-vora-2.1
    Image Pull Secret:
  Version:
    Component:  2.1.32.25-vora-2.1
    Package:    2.1.60
Status:
  Message:  Less available workers than Distributed Log requirements
  State:    Failed
Events:
  Type  Reason               Age   From                      Message
  ----  ------               ----  ----                      -------
            Update Vora Cluster  10m   vora-deployment-operator  Processing failed: less available workers than Distributeed Log requirements
            New Vora Cluster     10m   vora-deployment-operator  Started processing
    Timeout waiting for vora cluster! Please check the status of the cluster from above logs and kubernetes dashboard...
```

And some checks

```
       kubectl get pods --namespace=vora -w
    NAME                                                   READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
    vora-consul-0                                          1/1       Running     0          40m
    vora-consul-1                                          1/1       Running     0          39m
    vora-consul-2                                          1/1       Running     0          39m
    vora-deployment-operator-cc84bff65-hgtt4               1/1       Running     0          38m
    vora-elasticsearch-logging-v1-6cd4d466dc-gml9d         1/1       Running     0          38m
    vora-elasticsearch-logging-v1-6cd4d466dc-k882r         1/1       Running     0          38m
    vora-elasticsearch-retention-policy-5876dc64d4-6rb2l   1/1       Running     0          38m
    vora-fluentd-kubernetes-v1.21-95xt2                    1/1       Running     0          38m
    vora-fluentd-kubernetes-v1.21-f856k                    1/1       Running     0          38m
    vora-grafana-7b5454487b-xgbjt                          1/1       Running     0          38m
    vora-grafana-set-datasource-nwkt4                      0/1       Completed   1          38m
    vora-kibana-logging-c9565b88f-wm87j                    1/1       Running     0          38m
7    vora-kibana-logging-set-settings-h2vs2                 0/1       Completed   1          38m
    vora-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-57bb8bdb76-xlx4l    1/1       Running     0          38m
    vora-prometheus-node-exporter-m7znt                    1/1       Running     0          38m
    vora-prometheus-node-exporter-mp5ls                    1/1       Running     0          38m
    vora-prometheus-pushgateway-85dcf9f96f-j74j2           1/1       Running     0          38m
    vora-prometheus-pushgateway-cleaner-7ddf5657f-nwzrc    1/1       Running     0          38m
    vora-prometheus-server-797df6d8fb-5s7zd                2/2       Running     0          38m
    vora-security-operator-77f7fb9f5-zfs2z                 1/1       Running     0          40m
    vora-thriftserver-845646d95-5cz45                      2/2       Running     0          38m
    ^Cadmin@ip-172-20-41-35:/install/SAPVora-2.1.60-DistributedRuntime$   helm test kindred-clam
    Error: release: "kindred-clam" not found
    admin@ip-172-20-41-35:/install/SAPVora-2.1.60-DistributedRuntime$ kubectl exec vora-consul-0 consul members --namespace=vora | grep server
    vora-consul-0  100.96.1.9:8301   alive   server  0.9.0  2         dc1
    vora-consul-1  100.96.0.18:8301  alive   server  0.9.0  2         dc1
    vora-consul-2  100.96.1.10:8301  alive   server  0.9.0  2         dc1
```

Seems the installer did not create the cluster, at all:

kubectl get vc CRD -n vora
Error from server (NotFound): voraclusters.sap.com "CRD" not found

Is there a way to manually create the cluster? Or, is that even my issue or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

Issue above is error "Processing failed: less available workers than Distributeed Log requirements".

With Vora 2.1, by default you need 1 master and 3 workers. Minimum size is 1 master and 2 workers. To only use 2 workers with Vora 2.1, you need to change the replicationFactor for DLOG in deployment/helm/vora-cluster/values.yaml

Original (3 workers needed; one for each DLOG)

```
  dlog:
    replicationFactor: 2
    standbyFactor: 1
```

Minimum (2 workers; need to change replicationFactor)

```
  dlog:
    replicationFactor: 1
    standbyFactor: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How many nodes you have? Recommended size is 1 master & 2 worker nodes. Typically, no Vora pods are scheduled in master as it is non-schedule able node. So all pods are scheduled in worker nodes and dlog service requires at least 2 nodes. If you have 2 nodes including master then make make master schedulable. I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: I have 1 master and 2 nodes.
I did the isntall again but now using the new version "SP03 Patch0 for SAP DATA HUB DISTRIB " released 2 days ago 
It went through the old issue, but now its not able to use the EFS PV I provisioned for vsystem-vrep. Need to find out why this doesnt work now

Answer (score 0):

thanks Frank!

By decreasing the replication factor, I was now able to finish the install.

Now I can continue with the setup on the Hadoop cluster